# Only the last UISwitch in UITableViewCell fires

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to add a UISwitch in every cell (this works).  When I tap to toggle any switch other than the last one, they all give the last switches state until I change the last switches state

```
        `public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
            //---- declare vars
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (this._cellIdentifier);

            //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null) {
                // This changes the style of the UITableViewCell to the Default style
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, this._cellIdentifier);

                // Instantiate a cell accessory here
                uiSwitch = new UISwitch (new RectangleF (0f, 0f, 20f, 20f));
                uiSwitch.Tag = indexPath.Row;
                uiSwitch.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cell Switch value is now {0}", uiSwitch.On);
                };
                _vRMs.View.AddSubview (uiSwitch);

                // keep a reference to each cell you create,
                //  e.g. add them to a static List<UITableViewCell>.
                //  The GC won't be able to collect them so the event handler will work later.
                cells.Add (cell);
            }

            //---- create a shortcut to our item
            TableViewItem item = this._TableViewItemGroupList[indexPath.Section].Items[indexPath.Row];

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item.Name;
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
            cell.AccessoryView = uiSwitch;
            // cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = item.SubHeading;


            return cell;
        }`
```

I wanted to know if all this code was necessary to create a table with the UISwitches - being new to the iPhone dev world, I'm not sure.
I'm hoping this update will help in my cause.

```
`using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace eOneRaw {
    public partial class vRMs : UIViewController {

        #region FIELDS
        private string _ViewTitle = "RMs";
        private UITableView _TableView;
        private TableViewDataSource _TableViewDataSource;
        private List<TableViewItemGroup> _TableViewItemGroupList;
        private static vRMs _vRMs;
        #endregion      

        #region PROPERTIES
#endregion

        #region ViewDidLoad
        public override void ViewDidLoad () {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Title the Controller
            Title = _ViewTitle;

            #region UITableView Setup
            // Set up the table and data
            this.CreateTableItems ();

            // Create the UITableView
            _TableView = new UITableView() {
                Delegate = new TableViewDelegate(_TableViewItemGroupList),
                DataSource = _TableViewDataSource,
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth,
            };

            _TableView.SizeToFit();

            // Reposition and resize the receiver
            _TableView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height);

            // Add the table view as a subview
            this.View.AddSubview(_TableView);
#endregion

            #region Define the Look of the View
            var _barbtnCancel = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done);
            NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = _barbtnCancel;

            _barbtnCancel.Clicked += (s, e) => {
                this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
            };
#endregion

        } // end ViewDidLoad
#endregion

        #region METHODS
        public vRMs () {
            // Shouldn't ever happen
            _vRMs = this;
            Console.WriteLine (Environment.StackTrace);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning () {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
#endregion

        #region ALL TABLE FUNCTIONALITY

        #region CreateTableItems
        //========================================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a set of table items.
        /// </summary>
        // This is where you define your table
        protected void CreateTableItems () {
            _TableViewItemGroupList = new List<TableViewItemGroup> ();

            //---- declare vars
            TableViewItemGroup tGroup;

            tGroup = new TableViewItemGroup() { Name = "Regional Managers" };
            tGroup.Items.Add (new TableViewItem() { Name = "Chris" });
            tGroup.Items.Add (new TableViewItem() { Name = "Mike" });
            tGroup.Items.Add (new TableViewItem() { Name = "Dan" });
            tGroup.Items.Add (new TableViewItem() { Name = "Steve" });
            _TableViewItemGroupList.Add (tGroup);

            this._TableViewDataSource = new TableViewDataSource(_TableViewItemGroupList);
        }
#endregion

        #region CLASS TableViewDelegate
        // The delegate manages the transitions from view-to-view
        private class TableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate {
            private List<TableViewItemGroup> _TableViewItemGroupList;

            public TableViewDelegate(List<TableViewItemGroup> pList) {
                this._TableViewItemGroupList = pList;
            }

            public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
                return;
            }
        }
#endregion

        #region CLASS TableViewDataSource
        public class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource {

            protected List<TableViewItemGroup> _TableViewItemGroupList;
            string _cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell";
            private static UISwitch uiSwitch;
            static List<UITableViewCell> cells = new List<UITableViewCell> ();

            public TableViewDataSource (List<TableViewItemGroup> items) {
                this._TableViewItemGroupList = items;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Called by the TableView to determine how many sections(groups) there are.
            /// </summary>
            public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView) {
                return this._TableViewItemGroupList.Count;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Called by the TableView to determine how many cells to create for that particular section.
            /// </summary>
            public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section) {
                return this._TableViewItemGroupList[section].Items.Count;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Called by the TableView to retrieve the header text for the particular section(group)
            /// </summary>
            public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section) {
                return this._TableViewItemGroupList[section].Name;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Called by the TableView to retrieve the footer text for the particular section(group)
            /// </summary>
            public override string TitleForFooter (UITableView tableView, int section) {
                return this._TableViewItemGroupList[section].Footer;
            }

            #region UITableViewCell
            /// <summary>
            /// Called by the TableView to get the actual UITableViewCell to render for the particular section and row
            /// </summary>
            public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
                //---- declare vars
                UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (this._cellIdentifier);

                //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
                if (cell == null) {
                    // This changes the style of the UITableViewCell to the Default style
                    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, this._cellIdentifier);

                    // This changes the style of the UITableViewCell to the Subtitle style,
                    //  which displays a second line of text within the cell.
                    // cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, this._cellIdentifier);

                    // Instantiate a cell accessory here
                    uiSwitch = new UISwitch (new RectangleF (0f, 0f, 20f, 20f));
                    uiSwitch.Tag = indexPath.Row;
                    uiSwitch.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Cell Switch value is now {0}", uiSwitch.On);
                    };
                    _vRMs.View.AddSubview (uiSwitch);

                    // keep a reference to each cell you create,
                    //  e.g. add them to a static List<UITableViewCell>.
                    //  The GC won't be able to collect them so the event handler will work later.
                    cells.Add (cell);
                }

                //---- create a shortcut to our item
                TableViewItem item = this._TableViewItemGroupList[indexPath.Section].Items[indexPath.Row];

                cell.TextLabel.Text = item.Name;
                cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                cell.AccessoryView = uiSwitch;
                // cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = item.SubHeading;

                // Add an image if needed
                /*
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageName))
                {
                    cell.ImageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/" + item.ImageName );
                }
                */

                return cell;
            }
#endregion
        } // end TableViewDataSource Class
#endregion

        #region CLASS TableViewItemGroup
        //========================================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// A group that contains table items
        /// </summary>
        public class TableViewItemGroup {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Footer { get; set; }

            public List<TableViewItem> Items {
                get { return this._items; }
                set { this._items = value; }
            }

            protected List<TableViewItem> _items = new List<TableViewItem>();

            public TableViewItemGroup () {
            }
        }
#endregion

        #region CLASS TableViewItem
        //========================================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents our item in the table
        /// </summary>
        public class TableViewItem {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string SubHeading { get; set; }
            public string ImageName { get; set; }

            public TableViewItem () {
            }
        }
#endregion

#endregion

        #region OBSOLETE methods
        // ***************************** OBSOLETE
        // ***************************** OBSOLETE
        // ***************************** OBSOLETE
        [Obsolete]
        public override void ViewDidUnload () {
            base.ViewDidUnload ();

            // Clear any references to subviews of the main view in order to
            // allow the Garbage Collector to collect them sooner.
            //
            // e.g. myOutlet.Dispose (); myOutlet = null;

            ReleaseDesignerOutlets ();
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation) {
            // Return true for supported orientations
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        }
#endregion

    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

---

Firstly, I think your code sample misses a vital part?

What is the scope of the UISwitch variable? It seems like it's a class level reference?

---

Secondly, I think your code doesn't really handle cell reuse very well - the line `uiSwitch.Tag = indexPath.Row;` isn't called in the case of reuse.

---

Thirdly, I'm not too sure that your approach is really very scalable - although it would work for small lists

---

In all honestly, you are probably better off just creating a custom cell for this switch - and then using the values from those custom cells... To create a custom cell, see:

- using code in http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/User_Interface/Tables/Part_3_-_Customizing_a_Table%27s_Appearance
- using XIBs - http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/ and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  The UISwitch variable is at the class level.  You are correct.  I'm not sure why I used the .tag.  I guess I was hoping to use that as an index.  This is a small list.  I just can't think of how to get all the UISwithes to be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems pointed out by Stuart, the other problem is that you are recycling the cells, so you might end up with a recycled cell that is pointing to another state, nto what you wanted.

For a case like this, you could just use a unique key for each UISlider that you create to ensure that you never reuse a UISlider for two different variables.   Alternatively, you need to change your code so that the handler tells the different based on the IndexPath that acted on it.

Comment: I'm sure you hear this all the time - I'm a big fan of yours.
Now that the little school girl is out of me, would you be able to point me to some code that would accomplish this?  Mainly my issues are placing UISwitches dynamically into the cells - then to be able to reference these cells the 'correct way'.
I'm from C# ASP.net and windows environment and think I'm expecting something like a ListBox where there is a key
(hidden to reference) and a value (displayed).  So, any recommendations?

Comment: Most of the samples use interface builder.  If you could also, either recommend a book that writes pure MonoTouch without Interface Builder - or even better, please write one.

Comment: If it's a small list consider holding a list of UISwitches separately to the Cells - see how this code works in MonoTouch.Dialog - https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L260

Comment: Actually... if it's a small list, then just consider using MonoTouch.Dialog!

Comment: So would I use "BooleanElement" instead of "TableViewDataSource"?  In my updated code above, am I even approaching what I'm trying to do correctly?